# ANTLR grun (TestRig) tokens option does not recognize non-ASCII characters

Tags: utf-8, antlr4

I'm using the *grun.bat* (java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig %*).

Antlr version is 4.5

Running *grun.bat* with -tokens option on the input text results in *0 errors* but the non-ASCII characters are not recognized so their token is '*????*'

Adding the *encoding option* to the grun.bat:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig %*
```

results in getting an error per non-ASCII character, e.g.

> line 5:1 token recognition error at: 'ם'

The non-ASCII characters of the input text are included in utf-8.

How can I get the non-ASCII characters to be displayed correctly in the tokens?